# sort words in text by number of times cited in same line

Tags: linux, sorting, tr

look for most frequent words in text, sorted by numbers printed in same line for each number

```
    grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]' file.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

it gives

```
3 linux
3 fedora
2 ubuntu
2 mandriva
```

i look for

```
3 linux fedora
2 ubuntu mandriva


    grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]' file.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

the result

```
 3 linux
 3 fedora
 2 ubuntu
 2 mandriva
```

I look for

```
 3 linux fedora
 2 ubuntu mandriva
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to do it in a bash oneliner, but I have it here in short python script if that works for you.

```py
import os

preMergedList = os.popen("grep -o -E '\w+' file.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr").readlines()

countDict = {}
for line in preMergedList:
    count, word = line.split(None)
    count = int( count.strip() )
    word = word.strip()
    if not countDict.has_key( count ):
        countDict[count] = ""
    countDict[count] += word + " "

for count, wordString in sorted( countDict.iteritems(), reverse=True ):
    print count, wordString
```

Comment: it works but gives the number of characters instead of words, i look for words

Comment: that's just the base grep you are doing, I just took that from you, if you replace it with grep -o -E '\w+' it should work like that

Comment: You were Right Thank You